# Placement of SVG circle that lacks center coordinates

Tags: svg, d3.js

djvanderlaan's d3.js [Planetarium](http://bl.ocks.org/djvanderlaan/4953593) first defines a "sun" circle at the center of the SVG area:

```
svg.append("circle").attr("r", 20).attr("cx", w/2)
.attr("cy", h/2).attr("class", "sun")
```

and then defines two orbits around the sun (with code slightly rearranged for clarity here):

```
var planets = [
    { R: 300, r:  5, speed: 5, phi0: 90},
    { R: 150, r: 10, speed: 2, phi0: 190}
];

var container = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + w/2 + "," + h/2 + ")")

container.selectAll("g.planet").data(planets).enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "planet")
  .each(function(d, i) {

     d3.select(this).append("circle").attr("class", "orbit")
          .attr("r", d.R)

     d3.select(this).append("circle").attr("r", d.r).attr("cx",d.R)
          .attr("cy", 0).attr("class", "planet");

  });
```

The first circle in each group--the "orbit" circle--is never given center coordinates `cx` and `cy`.  That's not just in the source code; I looked at the "orbit" circles in the inspectors in three browsers, and there is no `cx` or `cy` for the orbit circles.  However, these circles are centered on the center of the SVG area, i.e. on x=w/2, y=h/2.  How does the browser know where to place these circles?  Does it inherit `cx` and `cy` from the enclosing `g` element?  From the "sun"?

Comment: I would assume planets are relative to the sun, so isn't it at 300 from the center of the sun (R: 300) at an angle of 90 degrees (phi0:90) with a radius of 5 (r:5). That seems to be all that is needed to locate it and size it.

Comment: I may not have been clear. For each orbiting planet, two circles are created. One represents the planet, and the other represents its orbit, i.e. the path that it takes. The orbit circles apparently have no center as far as D3 or SVG is concerned: They have no `cx` or `cy` values. The code doesn't give them these values, and the browser's inspector shows no values for `cx` and `cy`. Yet in the end, the orbit circles do have centers as far as the browser is concerned: It displays the orbit circles in particular locations.  How does the browser decide what values to fill in for `cx` and `cy`?

Comment: Oh the orbit not the planet, my bad. Yes. centered on the "g" as stated below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all svg elements inherit the transform and scale of their parent svg:g elements. You can use this to set a local center, as done here, or to play with scale and rotate with fine precision (since setting these all with the transform attribute can sometimes lead to unexpected results).

Often, people place their circle elements inside a parent g and position the g without ever setting cx/cy because a circle defaults to centering on the center of its parent. This isn't the case with svg:rect elements, which have to be offset to "center" them.

Comment: This is a bit misleading.  You can't "position" a `<g>` element.  However you *can* give it a `transform` attribute which is inherited by its children.