# How to get absolute coordinates of object inside a <g> group?

Tags: svg, d3.js

This may be a FAQ, so feel free to point me to another answer.  The topic is difficult to search on.

If I want to use d3.js to get an attribute that's explicitly declared in an SVG object, or that I've explicitly put there using D3, I can easily get the value of the attribute using `d3.select`.  For example, this prints 300:

```
...
<circle id="mycircle" r="10" cx="100" cy="200">
...
d3.select("#mycircle").attr("cx", 300);
console.log(d3.select("#mycircle").attr("cx"));
```

What if I don't explicit set the value of the attribute, but it is implicitly "set" from a `<g>` group?  Or: How can I use code to find out where a `<g>` group is centered?  I'd like some way of determining where in the absolute coordinate system of the `<svg>` object the things inside the `<g>` are.  If I knew where the `<g>` was, how it's oriented in space, etc., I could figure out where points inside it are.  How can I do that?

BigBadaboom remarks in a comment on an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26001232/placement-of-svg-circle-that-lacks-center-coordinates/26001719#26001719) that what is inherited is not a pair of coordinates, but a `transform` attribute.  So I can select a `<g>` and get the value of the transform attribute:

```
console.log(d3.select("#mygroup").attr("transform"));
```

which prints, for example:

"rotate(-125.93)translate(0,-25)"

Do I have to parse that to find out where the `<g>` is situated in the absolute coordinate system?

Comment: You're looking for the `getBBox()` function.  Don't have time to write a full answer now, but that's probably enough to get you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks @AmeliaBR for passing on that information quickly!  I didn't know about `getBBox()`.  Wonderful tool.  Doing some experimenting now.  Looks like it only provides coordinates relative to SVG the `<g>` group, though.  Rotations and translations in the `transform` attribute don't seem to affect the results of `getBBox()`.  Maybe there's a way of using it that I haven't thought of yet.

Comment: Note that at least for firefox getBBox() does not work on all elements

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Others here have already mentioned `SVGLocatable.getBBox()` which is useful for grabbing the bounding box of an element in terms of its own local coordinate system. Unfortunately, as you noticed, this doesn't take into account any of the transformations done on the element or on its parent elements.

There are a couple other functions available that will help you out a ton when dealing with those transforms.

`SVGLocatable.getScreenCTM()` gives you an `SVGMatrix` representing the transformations needed to convert from the viewport coordinates to the local coordinates of your element. This is great because it will take into account the transforms applied to the element it is called on, and any transforms applied to parent elements. Unfortunately, it also takes into account where exactly the element is on the screen, which means if you have content before your svg document, or even just some margins around it, the returned matrix will include that space as a translation.

`Element.getBoundingClientRect()` will allow you to account for that space. If you call this function on the SVG document itself, you can find out by how much the SVG is offset on the screen.

Then all you have to do is combine the two when you want to convert between coordinate systems. [**HERE**](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/coords.html#TransformMatrixDefined) is some good info on how an `SVGMatrix` works. The important thing to know for now is that an `SVGMatrix` is an object with six properties `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, and `f` which represent a transformation as follows:

[image: svg matrix equations]

Lets say you have a variable `svgDoc` which is a reference to the svg document (*not a d3 selection, but the element itself*). Then you can create a function that will convert to the coordinate system of an svg element `elem` as follows.

```
function convertCoords(x,y) {

  var offset = svgDoc.getBoundingClientRect();

  var matrix = elem.getScreenCTM();

  return {
    x: (matrix.a * x) + (matrix.c * y) + matrix.e - offset.left,
    y: (matrix.b * x) + (matrix.d * y) + matrix.f - offset.top
  };
}
```

Then, say you wanted to put a dot in the middle of `elem`, you could do something like this:

```
var bbox = elem.getBBox(),
    middleX = bbox.x + (bbox.width / 2),
    middleY = bbox.y + (bbox.height / 2);

var absoluteCoords = convertCoords(middleX, middleY);

var dot = svg.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', absoluteCoords.x)
  .attr('cy', absoluteCoords.y)
  .attr('r', 5);
```

<strike>Of course, you'd probably want to generalize the `convertCoords` function so you can pass in the target element, but hopefully that'll get you off in the right direction. Good luck!</strike>

A better implementation would be a factory that generates a conversion function for any given element and svg document context:

```
function makeAbsoluteContext(element, svgDocument) {
  return function(x,y) {
    var offset = svgDocument.getBoundingClientRect();
    var matrix = element.getScreenCTM();
    return {
      x: (matrix.a * x) + (matrix.c * y) + matrix.e - offset.left,
      y: (matrix.b * x) + (matrix.d * y) + matrix.f - offset.top
    };
  };
}
```

This could be used as follows given the same `elem` and `svgDoc` as the naive example:

```
var bbox = elem.getBBox(),
    middleX = bbox.x + (bbox.width / 2),
    middleY = bbox.y + (bbox.height / 2);

// generate a conversion function
var convert = makeAbsoluteContext(elem, svgDoc);

// use it to calculate the absolute center of the element
var absoluteCenter = convert(middleX, middleY);

var dot = svg.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', absoluteCenter.x)
  .attr('cy', absoluteCenter.y)
  .attr('r', 5);
```

Comment: You reference a nonexistent variable `elem` in your `convertCoords` function

Comment: "Then you can create a function that will convert to the coordinate system of an svg element `elem` as follows."

Comment: You should edit your answer to fix the scoping problem of elem. You should pass it and do calculations inside the function. It's bad practice to declare and use a variable in the way you have.

Comment: Okay, I agree. The point of the original example was just to illustrate how to use the `Element.getBoundingClientRect` and `SVGLocatable.getScreenCTM` methods, not to create a general purpose function. However, since that may be helpful to have, I've updated the answer with a better, more general implementation.

Comment: This function is great for updating an element's position relative to another that's animating. But, when the SVG is scaled down, or its coordinate system isn't equal to the document's pixels, the calculations are off. Is there a way to account for a scaled-down coordinate system?

Comment: Not working for me due to the reason in the previous comment **and** the fact it seems to ignore translations.

Answer (score 11):

@Jshanley's excellent answer is actually very easily implemented in raw JavaScript (or any framework) using SVGPoint's matrix transformation.

```
/**
* Get a new XY point in SVG-Space, where X and Y are relative to an existing element.  Useful for drawing lines between elements, for example

* X : the new X with relation to element, 5 would be '5' to the right of element's left boundary.  element.width would be the right edge.
* Y : the new Y coordinate, same principle applies
* svg: the parent SVG DOM element
* element: the SVG element which we are using as a base point.
*/
function getRelativeXY(x, y, svg, element){
  var p = svg.createSVGPoint();
  var ctm = element.getCTM();
  p.x = x;
  p.y = y;
  return p.matrixTransform(ctm);
}
```

See also:
[Rectangle coordinates after transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858479/rectangle-coordinates-after-transform)

In order to find the edges of your circle, for example:

```
var leftTangent = getRelativeXY(circle.cx-circle.r, circle.y, svg, circle);
var rightTangent = getRelativeXY(circle.cx+circle.r, circle.y, svg, circle);
var topTangent= getRelativeXY(circle.cx, circle.y-circle.r, svg, circle); 
var bottomTangent= getRelativeXY(circle.cx, circle.y+ circle.r, svg, circle);
var deadCenter= getRelativeXY(circle.cx, circle.y, svg, circle);
```

Admittedly not that interesting with a plain circle, but once the circle has been shifted or stretched it's a great tool for getting the coordinates.

[W3's Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#__svg__SVGPoint__matrixTransform)

[Microsoft's more easily understood tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh535760(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Your last line is incorrect. It should read return p.matrixTransform(ctm);

Comment: I'm also running into trouble where the SVG's viewbox and width/height have different aspect ratios. Trying to fix it now...

Comment: @MSC Ultimately if you set the aspect ratio, you can set either width or height, but not both.  If you set both the height and width, you've redefined the aspect ratio to fit those dimensions.

Comment: Would you be open to a tiny SVG consulting job by chance?

Comment: @Crashalot I'd be open to consider it, though the comments section isn't a great place to have this discussion.

Comment: @InfernalRapture sorry for the late reply. what's the best way to reach you? there are basically two modules: (1) Group of text/tspan elements that allows inline text editing and pixel perfect vertical/horizontal alignment to the parent; and (2) color picker like minicolors that allows for custom palette sections, linear gradient, and radial gradients. the SO answers for SVG textareas aren't good enough.

Answer (score 7):

D3 has a built in function to parse svg transforms: [`d3.transform`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Math#2d-transforms)

You could use it to get the translate array ([x, y]) of the transform, i.e.:

```
var transformText = d3.select("#mygroup").attr("transform");
var translate = d3.transform(transformText).translate;  //returns [0,-25]
```

Answer (score 7):

To get the bounds of an SVG element, you have two options:

1. `getBBox()` which works on all (graphical) SVG elements.  It gets the bounding box of the element in local coordinate space.  If the element has a `transform` attribute, it will affect the bbox, but if the parent element has a `transform`, it won't be reflected in the bbox returned.

   http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#InterfaceSVGLocatable
2. `getBoundingClientRect()` which is an HTML Element function, but also works for SVG elements.  It returns the bounds of the element in screen space (after all transforms have been applied).

   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect

Answer (score 2):

Nice demo here: https://codepen.io/netsi1964/pen/pWjwgP

```
point = point.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse())
```

Answer (score 2):

To me "absolute" could mean two things: screen pixels right and down from the SVG elements top-left corner, or userspace (i.e. viewBox coordinates).  I was interested in the latter.  For those wanting to take the last step of "transforming" the result of matrixTransform to absolute userspace coordinates, this worked for me:

```
function object_coords_to_userspace (x, y, object, svg) {
    // creates an SVGPoint with x,y coordinates inside an SVG element "object"
    // residing in parent svg, returns the location of the point in absolute
    // user space.

    // New point.
    point = svg.createSVGPoint();
    point.x = x;
    point.y = y;

    // New point location on screen where 0,0 is svg top left corner.
    coords_on_screen = point.matrixTransform(object.getCTM());

    // Convert screen coords to absolute userspace (i.e. respecting viewBox and svg element height and width).
    vphpx = svg.height.animVal.value;
    vpwpx = svg.height.animVal.value;



    // I thought I would need to implement this dumpster fire
    // (https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ComputingAViewportsTransform) to
    // get the viewPort dimensions (as opposed to the viewBox).  If I use
    // preserveAspectRatio=none, the results are correct because the viewport
    // shows the viewBox exactly.  Otherwise in general the viewport shows the
    // viewBox /plus/ some in order to make up the space and preserve the
    // aspect ratio (because I'm using the default "xMidyMid meet" value for
    // preserveAspectRatio.  Was hoping the <svg> element would have a simple
    // way to get the transform from screen to userspace!?, however I have
    // managed to find that the svg element's getCTM().inverse() produces a way
    // to transform screen pixels x,y (relative to the viewports top-left
    // corner) into userspace coordinates.  Phew!
    point2 = svg.createSVGPoint();
    point2.x = 0;
    point2.y = 0;
    res = point2.matrixTransform(svg.getCTM().inverse())
    vpl = res.x;
    vpt = res.y;
    
    point3 = svg.createSVGPoint();
    point3.x = svg.clientWidth;
    point3.y = svg.clientHeight;
    res = point3.matrixTransform(svg.getCTM().inverse())
    
    vpw = res.x - vpl;
    vph = res.y - vpt;
    
    return {x: coords_on_screen.x/vpwpx*vpw + vpl, y: coords_on_screen.y/vphpx*vph + vpt}
```

Comment: getCTM return null on firefox:

`function getCTMAlt(svgElement){`
  `return svgElement.getCTM() !== null ? svgElement.getCTM() document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg").createSVGMatrix();`
`}`