# Get coordinates of element relative to enclosing svg

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have an SVG with elements and groups of elements in it. I want to get the coordinates of an enclosed element, relative to the outer SVG.
Currently I am using `document.getElementById(elementid).getBBox().y`, which always returns 0.

Comment: `getBBox` will not take into account any transforms on the element or parent elements.   I believe you want to use [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you can use [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) for this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <svg width="500" height="500">
      <g transform="translate(100,100)rotate(45)">
        <text id="myText" x="10" y="10" style="fill:red">Hi Mom!</text>
      </g>
    </svg>
    <script>
      var rect = document.getElementById("myText").getBoundingClientRect();
      console.log("position is " + rect.top + "," + rect.left);
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This only works if the SVG itself is not scaled, and is positioned at 0,0.  Otherwise the coordinates map to the corner of the screen, not the SVG

Comment: @InfernalRapture is there a solution that works if the SVG is not at (0, 0)?

Comment: @Crashalot if you need specific coordinates in SVG-Space then I recommend writing a helper function to do a matrix transform.  It's a 5 liner, hopefully at some point they'll write a convenience method for it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37927466/1168319

If you need the coordinates in DOM space, that's what getBoundingClientRect() gives you (so if you're positioning an absolute DOM element, for example)

Comment: @InfernalRapture thanks! are these coordinates relative to the parent SVG element, or the root SVG element? thanks again.

Comment: @Crashalot it's relative to the SVG element passed to the helper as the 'svg' parameter.  So if you want to use the base SVG pass that.  If you want to include it as a child of a <g> you can pass that and you'll get coordinates relative to that.

Answer (score 4):

Using jQuery you do it like this: `var offset=svg.offset()` (gives you the absolute position of the svg) and then `var pos=elem.offset()` which gives you the absolute position of your element. Substract one from the other. Here svg is jQuery('svg') and maybe elem is jQuery('#idOfElement') for example.

I am too lazy to do the vanilla JS bit, and also I would not recommend using it. jQuery is attempting to be cross-browser and offset works very well on all browser implementations.

Also, you could try to leverage the browser positional system and set the position of the svg as 'relative', then elem.position() will give you the position relative to the first absolute parent element that has position relative or absolute.

`.svg { position: relative }`
or
`$('svg').css({position:'relative'})`

Then `$('#myElemId').position()` gives you the coordinates.