# D3.js: Rotate text on-spot

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pie-chart, coordinate-transformation

I have a pie chart with a 38 items in it. The radius is quite big and thus the text turns inward. The only problem I have is that the text stands upside down. I tried to fix that with just a normal rotation but that doesn't work, as it rotates around the center of my whole graph. I searched for answers and found smth similar. I tried to use [that code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049488/how-to-get-absolute-coordinates-of-object-inside-a-g-group) for my own purposed but failed.

I also checked an [example on b.locks](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/10633421) and as far as I understand it: Here they rotate and then just place it at the spot where it was before.

My text did a lot of stuff but hardly what I wanted. With the current state it stacks everything in the middle of my graph.

Here is my code:

```
var margin = { left:80, right:100, top:50, bottom:100 },
    height = 1200 - margin.top - margin.bottom, 
    width = 1280 - margin.left - margin.right,
    cwidth = 50;

var svg = d3.select("#pie-chart svg")
    .append("g")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 525 + "," + 450 + ")")
    .append("g")

/*gives the same numeric value to every object in the datafile (cuz they dont have numeric values) */     
var pie = d3.pie()
    .value(function(d){return 1})
;

//load data
d3.json("./data/unidata.json").then(function(data){
    //console.log(data);  
    var arc = d3.arc();

    var gs = svg.selectAll("g")
                .data(d3.values(data))
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", " + margin.top + ")")
    ;

    var arcIndexDictionary = {};
    var arcRingIndexSizeDictionary = {};


    // Visible arc
    gs.selectAll("path")
        .data(function(d,i) {       
            return pie(d).map(function(e){e.ringIndex = i; return e});
        })
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "nameArc")
        .attr("id", function(d,i) { 
            return d.data.name + "nameArc_"+i+i; 
        })
        .attr("d", 
            function(d, i) {
                var innerRadius = cwidth * d.ringIndex;
                var outerRadius = cwidth * (d.ringIndex + 1);
                var outerRadiusSlim = cwidth * (d.ringIndex + 1) + 2 * cwidth;
                // stores how many items are there in a ring in order to decide which text to flip
                arcRingIndexSizeDictionary[d.ringIndex] = i;
                // Main Arc - draws the rings
                if (d.ringIndex == 0){
                    arcIndexDictionary[d.data.name + "nameArc_"+i] = (innerRadius + outerRadius) / 2.0;
                    return arc.innerRadius(innerRadius).outerRadius(outerRadius)(d);
                }
                else if (d.ringIndex == 1){
                    arcIndexDictionary[d.data.name + "nameArc_"+i] = (innerRadius + outerRadiusSlim) / 2.04; 
                    return arc.innerRadius(innerRadius).outerRadius(outerRadiusSlim)(d);
                }
            }
        )
        .attr("fill", "grey") 
    ;

    // Placing text
    gs.selectAll(".nameText")
        .data(function(d,i) {       
            return pie(d).map(function(e){e.ringIndex = i; return e});
        })
        .enter()
        .append("text")
            .attr("class", "nameText")  
            .attr('dy', function(d, i, array){
            var ringItemCount = arcRingIndexSizeDictionary[d.ringIndex];
        }) 
        .append("textPath")
            .attr("xlink:href",function(d, i, array){
                return "#" + d.data.name + "nameArc_"+i+i;   
            })        
        .style("text-anchor", function(d, i){
                var ringItemCount = arcRingIndexSizeDictionary[d.ringIndex];    
                if(d.ringIndex == 1 && i <= ringItemCount/2) {
                    return "start"; //HERE
                } else {
                    return "start"
                }           
                })
        .attr("startOffset", function(d, i){ 
            if(d.ringIndex == 1 && i <= ringItemCount/2) 
                return "50%"; 
                if(d.ringIndex == 1) return "12%";   
                var ringItemCount = arcRingIndexSizeDictionary[d.ringIndex];
            }) 
        .text(function(d, i, array){ 
            if (d.ringIndex > 0)
            {return d.data.name};
            })
            .style('font-family', 'arial')
            .attr('font-size', function(d){
                if(d.ringIndex > 1){return '13px'} else {
                    return '9px';
                }})
    ;


    // ROTATE
    d3.selectAll("text")
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049488/how-to-get-absolute-coordinates-of-object-inside-a-g-group
    .attr("transform", function(d, i){
        if(d != undefined)
        {
            var ringItemCount = arcRingIndexSizeDictionary[d.ringIndex];          
            var rightPieCount = ringItemCount / 2;
            var halfPoint = rightPieCount / 2;  
            if(d.ringIndex == 1 && i <= ringItemCount/2)
            {
                // if you add 1 to x you need to add 180 / 19 * i
                var locationData = this.getBBox();
                var centerX = locationData.x + (locationData.width / 2);
                var centerY = locationData.y + (locationData.height / 2);
                // Fix their centralized locations 
                /*  
                if (locationData.y < 0){
                    centerX = centerX + i * 7;
                    centerY = centerY - (halfPoint - i) * 6;   
                } else {
                    centerX = centerX + (rightPieCount - i) * 7;
                    centerY = centerY - (-(halfPoint - i) * 6);
                } */
                console.log(centerX, centerY);
                var result = "";
                result += 'translate(' + centerX + ',' + centerY + ')';
                result += 'rotate(180)';
                return result;
            }
        }
    })
    ;

    // middle text
    gs.append("text")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr('font-size', '0.8em')
        .attr('font-family', 'arial')
        .style('fill', 'white')
        .text("Inf FB") 

})
```

I'm also adding my data-set in a shortened version below.
As I am new to D3 I would really appreciate if someone could tell me how to achieve that the text rotates on spot or direct me in another direction on how to achieve my goal :) Thanks a lot.

```
{   "Leitsatz": [],
    "Profs": [
        {
            "name": "Softwarekonstruktion"
        },
        {
            "name": "Verteilte Systeme"
        },
        {
            "name": "Angew. Softwaretechnik"
        },
        {
            "name": "Sicherheit"
        },
        {
            "name": "(W1) Sicherheit/ Sicherheitsmgmt."
        },
        {
            "name": "Rechennetze"
        },
        {
            "name": "Theoretische Inf."
        },
        {
            "name": "(W1) Theoretische Inf.)"
        },
        {
            "name": "(W1) Informatikbildung)"
        },
        {
            "name": "(W1) Mobile Services"
        },
        {
            "name": "(W1TT) Informatik"
        },
        {
            "name": "Wiss. Rechnen (DKRZ)"
        },
        {
            "name": "Wiss. Visualisierung (Dir. RRZ)"
        },
        {
            "name": "Daten Enginieering"
        },
        {
            "name": "Simulation & Visualisierung"
        },
        {
            "name": "Alg. Molekulares Design"
        },
        {
            "name": "(W1) Angewandte Bioinf."
        },
        {
            "name": "Rechnerg. Bioinformatik"
        },
        {
            "name": "Maschinelles Lernen"
        },
        {
            "name": "Autonome Systeme"
        },
        {
            "name": "(W1TT) Sem. Systeme"
        },
        {
            "name": "Wissenstechnologien"
        },
        {
            "name": "Signalverarbeitung"
        },
        {
            "name": "Bildverarbeitung"
        },
        {
            "name": "(W1TT) Assistenzsysteme"
        },
        {
            "name": "Sprachverarbeitung"
        },
        {
            "name": "Sprachtechnologie"
        },
        {
            "name": "Multimodale Systeme"
        },
        {
            "name": "Mensch-Computer-Interaktion"
        },
        {
            "name": "Usability & Softwareergonomie"
        },
        {
            "name": "Ethik in der Informationstechnik"
        },
        {
            "name": "IT-Gestaltung"
        },
        {
            "name": "(W1TT) Wirtschaftsinformatik"
        },
        {
            "name": "(W1TT) Betriebssystem"
        },
        {
            "name": "(W1TT) Adaptive Systeme"
        },
        {
            "name": "IT Management"
        },
        {
            "name": "Digital Technochange"
        },
        {
            "name": "Datenbanken"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To rotate something about its centre you need to move its centre to (0, 0), them rotate it, then move it back. So where you are adding the transforms, do:

```
// ROTATE
d3.selectAll("text")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    if (d !== undefined) {
        var ringItemCount = arcRingIndexSizeDictionary[d.ringIndex];
        if (d.ringIndex == 1 && i <= ringItemCount / 2) {
            var locationData = this.getBBox();
            var centerX = locationData.x + (locationData.width / 2);
            var centerY = locationData.y + (locationData.height / 2);

            var result = 'translate(' + centerX + ',' + centerY + ')';
            result += 'rotate(180)';
            result += 'translate(' + (-centerX) + ',' + (-centerY) + ')';
            return result;
        }
    }
});
```